# Cannot get Backup Exec 11d to recognize my RDX device on windows server?

Tags: backup, backupexec, symantec

We have Backup Exec 11d for windows server running on windows server that currently backups up our data on tape drive. We purchased an 500GB RDX drive to replace the tape drives but cannot get Backup Exec 11d to recognize our RDX device on windows server? It does not show up under devices tab in backup exec. It is however visible in disk management and works for all other uses. I am thinking it could be the version of backup exec?

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: If I recall correctly isn't d2d a "pay for" option? Or it might be only in netbackup

Comment: 11d does have "backup-to-disk" (p218 BackupExec 11d Admin Guide) and allows removable disks, but they should show up in Devices.  Maybe it's one of those 'features' that you HAVE to go through the wizard for?

Comment: It says that the device should be recognized automatically, I am stumped! :-(

Comment: Did you install the driver for your RDX drive?

Answer (score 1):

The RDX drive needs to be a configured as a removable backup-to-disk folder. I'm assuming your RDX device is connected via USB. Create a filesystem on the drive and a map a B2D folder to it.

[image]

Comment: Can I do this if my RDX does not even show up in symantec? My RDX currently has a NTFS file system.

Comment: Install the RDX device driver for your manufacturer's drive. Can you see it in the Windows system devices list?

Comment: Yes it is in the Windows system devices list. It is accessible and usable in all other instances, just not backup exec, I am wondering if I need to upgrade to a newer version. Also, all updates are up to date.

Comment: Solution found: I had to upgrade to a newer version of Exec. I was worried about this as I had to spend some coin but it solved my problem. Thanks all for the tips though.